# How do I enable NTSC filters / shaders + scanlines in higan?

Tags: emulation, snes

I've tried both the ZSNES and the Snes9x SNES emulators to play SNES ROMs, and I've always preferred enabling their built-in [NTSC filter (RGB)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151228013555/http://www.slack.net/~ant/libs/ntsc.html) and scanlines.

I'm looking to do the same for the [higan](http://byuu.org/emulation/higan/) emulator. So I searched and found [these shaders (quark-shaders)](https://github.com/hizzlekizzle/quark-shaders). While some of its shaders work fine in higan, selecting 'NTSC' gives me a black screen, with the sound still playing, on both windowed and full-screen modes.

I'm using higan v094, 64-bit, higan-performance.exe on Windows 7, 64-bit. My GPU is an AMD HD 6750 and my LCD monitor's native resolution is 1366 x 768.

Here's my higan *settings.bml* configuration file contents:

```
Video
  Driver: OpenGL
  Synchronize: false
  Shader: C:/Games/Emulators/Multi-platform/higan/Video Shaders/NTSC.shader/
  ScaleMode: 1
  AspectCorrection: true
  ColorEmulation: true
  MaskOverscan: false
    Horizontal: 8
    Vertical: 8
  Saturation: 100
  Gamma: 100
  Luminance: 100
  StartFullScreen: false

Audio
  Driver: XAudio2
  Synchronize: true
  Frequency: 44100
  Latency: 20
  Resampler: 2
  Volume: 100
  Mute: false

Input
  Driver: Windows
  Focus
    Pause: true
    AllowInput: false

Timing
  Video: 60.0
  Audio: 44100.0

Server
  Hostname: 
  Username: 
  Password: 

Library
  Selection: 1
  MediaMode: 0
  ShowOnStartup: true
```